# Cannot store data in data type POINT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

There is a database with a table  locations,

today I insert the ROW

`INSERT INTO 'locations' ('id', 'coordinates') VALUES (NULL, ST_GeomFromText('-122.325133 37.566563'));`

but i use to check the result
`SELECT * FROM 'locations';`

only return

`1, null, 2,null`

may i know how can store the coordinates data , thank you

i use 10.2.38-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

i have try `INSERT INTO 'locations' ('id', 'coordinates') VALUES (NULL, ST_GeomFromText(-122.325133 37.566563));`

but is syntax

Comment: Have you tried `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.325133 37.566563)')`?

Comment: I try run `INSERT INTO 'locations' ('id', 'coordinates') VALUES (NULL, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.325133 37.56656)',0));` now the result is [GEOMETRY - 25 B]

Comment: and `ST_PointFromText('POINT(-122.325133 37.566563)')` or `PointFromText('POINT(-122.325133 37.566563)')`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You use incorrect quoting symbols for objects names - must be not single quotes but backticks (or none if the object name is not keyword / reserved). Now you try to insert into string literals..
2. You use incorrect WKT literal.

Finally:

```sql
INSERT INTO locations (id, coordinates)
  VALUES (NULL, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-122.325133 37.566563)'));
```